# What is the difference between $var and ($var) in php?

Tags: php, return, expression

As related to this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

> You should never use parentheses around your return variable when returning by reference, as this will not work. You can only return variables by reference, not the result of a statement. If you use return ($a); then you're not returning a variable, but the result of the expression ($a) (which is, of course, the value of $a).

I do understand what the note is talking about but a variable in parentheses becomes a statement / expression? What are the other differences between $var and ($var) (as well as any aspects related to this)?

The value of ($var) is different than the value of $var ?

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday, any reason?

Comment: Next time don't accept answers which dont answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put a variable in parentheses, it becomes an expression whose value is the contents of the variable.

This only makes a difference if you're trying to assign by reference. A reference creates an alias that links two variables to each other, so it doesn't work if you have just the contents of the variable.

So if you have a function like:

```
function &ret_by_reference() {
    $var = "something";
    return $var; // correct
    return ($var); // incorrect
}
```

The `&` in the function statement means it returns the variable by reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Some more on that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935313/returning-by-reference-parentheses-around-a-return-variable

Comment: And the value of "$var" (no parentheses) is different than "the contents of the variable"?

Comment: When you're assigning by reference it is, it's becomes a link to the variable itself.

Comment: Do you understand what references are? If not, you should probably bone up on that section of the PHP documentation.